# Swift - how to pass managed object context to different view controllers

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I put the core data stack in its own file as shown below. I read that using dependency injection is the best way to pass the managed object context. So in each of a handful of VCs, I declare the following property:

```
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext?
```

Now, the tricky part is getting the moc from my stack to the different VCs. Which seems like a great place for a singleton, but assuming that's a bad idea, I guess I would use the code below in CoreDataStack:

```
let controller = self.window!.rootViewController as! ViewController
let context = self.persistentContainer.viewContext
controller.managedObjectContext = context
```

But that leaves me with a few questions:

 1) Where in `CoreDataStack` should I include the code above? In the `App Delegate` it would go in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, but that's not really an option now.

2) Writing the above code for every single vc that needs a context seems bad. I guess I could loop through all the VCs. I've seen the moc passed using didSet too, but that doesn't seem quite right either.

**CoreData Stack**

```
class CoreDataStack {    
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Model")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
         if let error = error as NSError? {
             fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
         }
     })
     return container
}()

func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will happily upvote and heed the advice of any answer which explains to me why it is such a bad idea to just be done with it and shamelessly use a singleton for the *view* managed object context in simple iOS apps.  I typically make it a property of the app delegate.

Comment: Instead of passing contexts, I would pass `CoreDataStack`. I would declare it in the topmost view controller and pass it down to other view controllers from there. Couldn't you do that? I wouldn't set the context on a view controller from within `CoreDataStack`, that seems like a violation of of encapsulation.

Comment: To be honest, I figured out how to use dependency injection in about 80% of my project, but really struggled after that. So I ended up going back to using a singleton for now. I do plan to revisit this question soon and appreciate the help.